# Resampling operation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, sampling

I am reading [from an arXiv.org paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3750) the following math text:

"Let $x\in \{−1, 1\}^I$ be random and uniform, and let $y$ be obtained from $x$ by resampling each coordinate with probability $\varepsilon$ independently,
where $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Then $y$ is referred to as an $\varepsilon$-noise of $x$ and $\mathbb{E}(x_iy_i) = 1 - \varepsilon$."

My question is how in the probability theory we define the resampling operation considered in the text above ? I am sorry for the problem but I cannot find any answer in google

Comment: You should cite the specific text from which you read this.  As I read this passage (without benefit of context), it says that for each component $x_i$ we determine $y_i$ either by "resampling" from $\{-1,1\}$ or by keeping $y_i = x_i$.  We resample with independent probability $\varepsilon$ in each component (and keep the $x_i$ component with probability $1-\varepsilon$).

Comment: The text comeas from the following arxiv manuscript (page 4): http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3750. I cannot understand what the authors mean by the resampling operation, that is, how to obtain the random variable $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I can confirm my understanding of the authors' meaning as outlined in my first comment.  Would it help to see why the procedure for choosing $y_i$ given $x_i$ yields $\mathbb{E}(x_i y_i) = 1 - \varepsilon$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is more clear but it will be better if I write how I understand your answer. Given $i\in I$, the random variable $y_i$ is such that $y_i = x_i$ on the set $A$ of measure $1-\varepsilon$ and $y_i$ is any measurable function with values in $\{-1,1\}$ on $\Omega\setminus A$. Then $\mathbb{E}(x_iy_i) = 1\cdot P(A) + \mathbb{E}(x_iy_i \mathbb{1}_{\Omega\setminus A})$. And here is the difficult point because I still do not understand how to compute $\mathbb{E}(x_iy_i \mathbb{1}_{\Omega\setminus A})$, by use of your definition

Comment: I have answered with a computation of the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure the authors describe to get $y$ from $x$ is done independently on each component.

With probability $\varepsilon$ we choose $y_i$ to be a random (uniform independently distributed) value of $\pm 1$.  With probability $1-\varepsilon$ we keep $y_i = x_i$.

So let's compute the expected value of $x_i y_i$.  With chance $\varepsilon/2$ we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=-1$.  Also with chance $\varepsilon/2$ we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=1$.  Finally with chance $1-\varepsilon$ we keep $y_i = x_i$.

Now the latter outcomes have $x_i y_i = 1$ and so contribute $(1-\varepsilon)$ to the expected value.  The first two outcomes have opposite signs but equal probability, so together they net contribute zero to the expected value.  Thus the expected value $\mathbb{E}(x_i y_i) = 1-\varepsilon$.

Note that the authors have a footnote about this, contrasting their resampling procedure with the "bit-flipping" procedure defined in the 1999 paper by Benjamini et al.  The difference in definitions contributes a factor of two in the formulas on $\varepsilon$, and in the opinion of the present authors gives simpler expressions.

Comment: I am sorry that I am asking one more time but I still have a problem to see that the first two outcomes contribute zero to the expected value. Their cotribution is exactly $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_A x_i) - \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B x_i)$, where $A$ is the event that we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=1$ and $B$ is the event that we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=-1$. Now, why the expression $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_A x_i) - \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B x_i)$ is equal to $0$ ?

Comment: No problem.  The expected value is the sum of values of possible outcomes times their probability.  So in the first outcome the value is $x_i y_i = -x_i$, since $y_i = -1$.  In the second outcome the value is $x_i y_i = x_i$, since $y_i = 1$.  So those two contribute $(-x_i)\varepsilon/2 + (x_i)\varepsilon/2 = 0$ to the expected value, no matter what the probability $\varepsilon$ is.  It is the third outcome, with value $1$ and probability $1-\varepsilon$, which gives us $\mathbb{E}(x_i y_i) = 0 + 1\cdot(1-\varepsilon) = 1 - \varepsilon$.

Comment: Maybe you missed that when we "resample" for $x_i$, the chances that $y_i = 1$ and $y_i = -1$ are equal.

Comment: Probably I understand. From your answer I deduce that, in the paper,  $x_i$ is a deterministic constant and after "resampling" $y_i$ is a random variable. Is it OK ?

Comment: Have a try at refreshing the screen and reading the last two comments I made.  The fact that that $\mathbb{E}(x_i y_i) = 1 - \varepsilon$ and so does not depend on $x_i$ is true even if we regard $x_i$ as a random variable rather than a "deterministic constant".

Comment: Maybe I still miss something but If we admit $x_i$ to be random, then for $x_i:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ the contribution is exactly $\int_A x_i(\omega) \, d\omega - \int_B x_i(\omega) \, d\omega$, where as previously, A is the event that we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=1$ and $B$ is the event that we "resample" $x_i$ and get $y_i=−1$. Why the difference of the integrals is equal to zero ?

Comment: The events $A,B$ you defined are mutually exclusive and equally likely.  That is, when choosing a resampled component, $\pm 1$ are chosen uniformly.

Comment: But how to deduce from $A\cap B$ and $P(A)=P(B)$ that $\int_A x_i(\omega)\, d\omega = \int_B x_i(\omega)\, d\omega$

Comment: The value of $x_i$ is not affected by the events $A,B$, which occur after random variable $x$ is evaluated.  In this case the probability measure is discrete.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of context given, this means *Sampling again from underlying distribution*. So you end up updating some of your coordinates with probabilities $\epsilon$, while others are not updated with probability $1-\epsilon$.